# Error while importing a text file and deleting the Range name that start with _

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to import the text file(whose content is pasted here) in excel 2010.

Sample
`0.000336179308182416   0.0003623072328649  0.000330580466347818       0.000328403140930966 0.000326536860231208    0.000316583362896417    0.000331824654826285    0.000376926431150615    0.000359196764802228    0.00035110955014428 0.000340222914920751    0.00038594678488213 0.000374438054920212    0.00038719097133022 0.000356708390252258    0.000355464204180755    0.000362307232454562    0.000408031102693052    0.00042793809249897 0.000361685139135481    =AVERAGE(B2:U2) =MEDIAN(B2:U2)  =STDEV.P(B2:U2) 0.000317516503116533    0.000324670578360742    0.000343644429001611    0.00031720545739935 0.000316272316168398    0.000322182204319699    0.000319071737757159    =AVERAGE(B2:AE2)    =MEDIAN(B2:AE2) =STDEV.P(B2:AE2)`

The import worked properly. After the text file is opened in excel, I wrote the following VBA code to delete the range names that start with _.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
  If Mid$(n.Name, 1, 1) = "_" Then
    MsgBox ("The file being deleted is " + n.Name)
     n.Delete
  End If
 Next n
End Sub
```

and saved the file. Now again I opened this saved xlsm file and I have the msg displayed "The file being deleted is _xlfn.STDEV.P".

Even though I have an STDEV.P function specified in my text file,I dont know from where this range name has been added to the `ActiveWorkBook.Names` collection. And the subsequent delete operation is also throwing an error,as the range name is a excel funtion name. Please help me to rectify this issue.

Comment: inspect first your range names in *menu >> formulas >> Name manager*

Comment: it is not listed out there. Infact the Name manager is empty

Comment: Are you generating the Names programmatically and if so please post this code (by editing your answer?)

Comment: search in Google for `_xlfn` as this is a special restricted type of prefix added by Excel in some situation.

Comment: I read in some forums that _xlfn is added as a marker when a 2010 workbook is saved in a 97-03 format for any formulas containing functions which where supported only in 2010. But I was not able to figure out why a range name(_xlfn.STDEV.P) is created even though I am saving the sheet in 2010 format

Answer (score 0):

Range names that start with _xlfn is created by excel, so any attempt to delete these range names will throw error. So I have avoided the deletion of range names that start with _xlfn.

```
For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If Mid$(n.Name, 1, 5) = "_xlfn" Then
        continue
    Else  
        n.Delete
    End If
Next n
```